# Vimeo Background Video Wont Loop on ipad but does on all other devices

Tags: vimeo

I am a pro member of Vimeo using Background Videos through out a website. These videos have no audio, and loop at the top of the page. It works well, except on an ipad, which only plays the video once then stops.

Here is the code i'm using:

```
<div id="interiorHeaderVideo" class="vimeo-wrapper">
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/408561072?background=1" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
</div>
```

I am loading Vimeo player.js in the header using:

```
<script async="true" src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

Here is an example of the video not looping at the top on ipad. (must view on ipad to see the issue, it does loop on other devices): 
https://www.synteract.com/Therapeutic-Expertise/Neuroscience

I've tried to search why this might be. I know mobile devices don't like to auto play videos, but I haven't heard anyone say anything about mobile devices stopping a video from looping.

Is there any reason ipad would prevent looping while other devices allow it?

Comment: What model iPad is it, and what version of iOS is installed on it?

Comment: iPad (6th generation) software Version: 13.3.1
Model Number: MRJN2LL/A